# give logged in user different color

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a login and once you login you get to see a list with all the users in the database.

I want to highlight the logged in user in that list with a color like red or something. How can I do this?

Comment: You could set different styles of the html elements, maybe the border-color or background-color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
<table>
<?php 
foreach($users as &$user) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td<?php if ($user == $currentUser) print(" style=\"background-color=red;\""); ?>>
            <?php print($user); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```